# Two Combination Lists from One List

Tags: python, iteration, combinations

I am a python beginner. I am trying to get two combination lists from one list.

For example, I have a list:

```
c = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want to get every possible combination using every four items to fill two lists. There are going to be `((2^4)/2)-1` possibilities.

```
c1 = [1]  c2 = [2, 3, 4]
c1 = [2]  c2 = [1, 3, 4]
c1 = [3]  c2 = [2, 3, 4]
c1 = [4]  c2 = [1, 2, 3]
c1 = [1, 2]  c2 = [3, 4]
c1 = [1, 3]  c2 = [2, 4]
c1 = [1, 4]  c2 = [2, 3]
```

The function usually works for this kind of task is `itertools`, but I cannot choose the number of lists produced by `itertools.combination`.

The function only allows me to choose how many items per one list should be.

For example, If I try following function,

```
print list(itertools.combinations(c, 2))
```

I can get an outcome only like this.

```
[(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)]
```

I searched pretty hard to find this, but I couldn't find anything.

**Update**

Oh my poor English is causing such a confusion! I totally changed my example. I wanted to allocate the 4 items to 2 lists. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Why would there be 10 choose 2 possibilities? If each item can go in one of two lists, that's 2^10. On the other hand, the pattern you posted suggests you're splitting the list between two items, in which case there would only be 9 possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unsure as to what your understanding of **10 choose 2** is. The output you receive from `list(itertools.combinations(c, 2))` is what is mathematically defined as *10C2*.

---

### EDIT

From the edit to your question, it appears that you want an entirely different kind of combinations. The number of outcomes would still not be 45, but instead: **10C1 + 10C2 + 10C3 + 10C4 + 10C5**.

---

I expect the following should help you move forward:

```
for i in range(1, 6):
    for c1 in itertools.combinations(c, i):
            c1 = set(c1)
            c2 = set(c) - c1
            print c1, c2
```

The above code was inspired by [this (deleted) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33362072/1190388) by [CSZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/595870/csz).

---

The output received when `range(1, 3)` is used:

```
[1] [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[2] [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[3] [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[4] [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[5] [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[6] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[7] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10]
[8] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]
[9] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]
[10] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2] [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 3] [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 4] [2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 5] [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 6] [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 7] [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10]
[8, 1] [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]
[1, 9] [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]
[1, 10] [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[2, 3] [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[2, 4] [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[2, 5] [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[2, 6] [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[2, 7] [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10]
[8, 2] [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]
[9, 2] [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]
[2, 10] [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[3, 4] [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[3, 5] [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[3, 6] [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[3, 7] [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10]
[8, 3] [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]
[9, 3] [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]
[10, 3] [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[4, 5] [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[4, 6] [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[4, 7] [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10]
[8, 4] [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]
[9, 4] [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]
[10, 4] [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[5, 6] [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[5, 7] [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10]
[8, 5] [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10]
[9, 5] [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10]
[10, 5] [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[6, 7] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10]
[8, 6] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10]
[9, 6] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10]
[10, 6] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
[8, 7] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10]
[9, 7] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10]
[10, 7] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
[8, 9] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10]
[8, 10] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
[9, 10] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I totally rewrote my example.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering how to exclude cases that `c1==c2` is `True`.

Answer (score 2):

```
l = [1,2,3,4, 5,  6, 7, 8]

print [[l[:i], l[i:]] for i in range(1, len(l))]
```

If you want all combinations. you can do like this.

```
print [l[i:i+n] for i in range(len(l)) for n in range(1, len(l)-i+1)]
```

or

```
itertools.combinations
```